# How to check multiple different criteria about same value

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Imagine that I am testing a simple JS class which looks like:

```
class Test {
  static id = 0;
  static defaultConfig = { default: 'value' };
  static makeTest(config) {
    return new Test(config);
  }
  constructor(config = {}) {
    this.id = Test.id++;
    this.config = { ...Test.defaultConfig, ...config };
  }
};
```

I want to test the `Test.makeTest` static method. I want to make sure it returns an instance of `Test`, and that the instance's config is determined by the parameter passed to `Test.makeTest`. I could do the following:

```
describe('Test.makeTest', () => {
  it('works in simple case', () => {
    
    const test = Test.makeTest({ a: 1, b: 2 });
    expect(test).toEqual(expect.any(Test));
    expect(test).toHaveProperty('id', 0);
    expect(test).toHaveProperty('config', expect.objectContaining({ a: 1, b: 2 }));
    
  });
});
```

How can I write an equivalent test (with multiple expectations) *without* assigning a reference to the `Test` instance? For example, it would be nice to be able to chain `.toEqual` and `.toHaveProperty`:

```
describe('Test.makeTest', () => {
  it('works in simple case', () => {
    
    expect(Test.makeTest({ a: 1, b: 2 }))
      .toEqual(expect.any(Test))
      .toHaveProperty('id', 0)
      .toHaveProperty('config', expect.objectContaining({ a: 1, b: 2 }));
    
  });
});
```

but this isn't supported (these methods all return `undefined`).

Overall I hope to boost the readability and lower the cognitive overhead of tests.

Comment: You can't - as you say, chaining isn't supported, the expect interface isn't fluent. And if you built (or used, e.g. [this](https://github.com/mattphillips/jest-chain)) something to support it, as that isn't standard in the framework being used, that would _increase_ the cognitive overhead of the tests

Comment: Looks like it's been explicitly rejected upstream: https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/3998

Answer (score -1):

You could keep a reference to the `expect(someValue)` call, but this admittedly doesn't really solve the issue at all:

```
describe('Test.makeTest', () => {
  it('works in simple case', () => {
    
    let exp = expect(Test.makeTest({ a: 1, b: 2 }));
    exp.toEqual(expect.any(Test));
    exp.toHaveProperty('id', 0);
    exp.toHaveProperty('config', expect.objectContaining({ a: 1, b: 2 }));
    
  });
});
```